# Generate UUID in application which has 40000 request per month

Tags: uuid, timeuuid

I need to maintain unique id for application which has 40000 application per month. I am considering using simple UUID. Is there any better approach of creating it?

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Timebased or random is good, i don't want to have any duplication in this id generation.

Comment: why do you think you will have duplicates?